# Vba running timer on userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a userform in workbook1 and created a running timer in it. When I run the code the timer starts.

Now I open another instance of excel. Open workbook2 from it. I am able to do this much and i can run other macros or work on workbook2. The only problem is when I close workbook2 it stops my running macro in workbook1 and the running timer stops.

Any help how i can avoid this thing. I want my timer to act as a stopwatch while use can work seamlessly on other workbooks.

Comment: How do you open the 2nd instance, and which version of Excel? If each instance is running in its own process, they're not going to interfere. If you need help with your macro, including it in the post is the only way we can see what's going on.

Comment: I am using excel 2016. I am opening workbook2 through start button > excel 2016> open.             Also I am running userform1.show vb modeless on workbook open event in workbook1.        Code for running timer is usual timer code.